# Getting Response from Spring boot to React-Admin Framework

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, jwt, react-admin

React-Admin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-admin

This is the response from the spring-boot when we send the bearer token to the spring-boot app from the Postman Application:

```
[
    {
        "uid": 2,
        "name": "cus",
        "email": "cus@gmail.com",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "role": "CUSTOMER"
    }
]
```

How to send the Bearer Token to the spring-boot, so that the response has to render in the react-admin framework which is installed?

This is the Admin Dashboard in the React-Admin:

```
const AdminDash = () => (
  <Admin dashboard={Dashboard}  dataProvider={dataProvider}>
    <Resource name="posts" list={PostList} />
  </Admin>
)
```

in the above code because of the `name="posts"` it will look for the `posts` but the spring-boot doesn't have any (which i mentioned the code block above as spring boot response). How to get the details from the spring boot when I don't have anything like `posts` in my spring boot backend?
If I remove the `name="posts"` it consoling this : `No routes matched location "/undefined"`

This is the PostList.jsx which is used to show the data to the frontend:

```
export const PostList = () => {
    const isSmall = useMediaQuery(theme => theme.breakpoints.down('sm'));
    return (
        <List>
            <Datagrid>
            <TextField source="id" />
            <TextField source="name" />
            </Datagrid>
        </List>
    );
}
```

By asking ChatGpt for the JWT Token sending it suggest this but not working don't know why:

```
const httpClient = (url, options = {}) => {
  if (!options.headers) {
    options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' });
  }
  // console.log("in httpclient now wow !") // consoled to check is it working but not !!!!
  // Retrieve the JWT token from local storage
  const token = localStorage.getItem('jwtToken');

  // Add the Authorization header with the JWT token
  options.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);

  return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
};
const dataProvider = jsonServerProvider('http://localhost:8080/api/v1', httpClient);
```

PS : If this can't work out, kindly recommend some npm packages like this which is easy to implement in react

The response has to be render in the react-admin used pages from the spring boot using JWt Token, or need some other packages like this